# MySQL join on tables with duplicate index values

Tags: mysql, join

We have two MySQL tables, that when joined using a standard join are creating duplicate results. The reason being that the common field used to join them is not unique. We've tried multiple variations, but are unable to get the correct results. Hopefully someone can point us in the right direction.

[Table A / ws_511_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaMXV.png)

[Table B / ws_583_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovMgX.png)

The correct output should look like this:

[Correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbxZv.png)

The query that has got us closest to the correct output (not all columns have been included here):

```
SELECT a.col_3 AS Data, SUM(a.col_4) AS `October 2016`, SUM(a.col_5) AS `November 2016`, SUM(b.col_4) AS `February 2017`, SUM(b.col_5) AS `March 2017` FROM ws_511_1 a LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ws_583_1 b GROUP BY col_3) b ON b.col_3 = a.col_3 WHERE a.id!='1' GROUP BY a.col_3
```

The output of this query is:

[Incorrect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9ojX.png)

You will notice that October and November are correct, but the joined column results are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the group  by result for the left   table

```
  SELECT  a.col_3 AS Data
    , SUM(a.col_4) AS `October 2016`
    , SUM(a.col_5) AS `November 2016`
    , b.`February 2017`
    , b.`March 2017` 
  FROM ws_511_1 a 
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT col_3
        , SUM(b.col_4) AS `February 2017`
        , SUM(b.col_5) AS `March 2017`  
        FROM ws_583_1 b 
        GROUP BY col_3
  ) b ON b.col_3 = a.col_3 
  WHERE a.id!='1' 
  GROUP BY a.col_3 , , b.`February 2017`, b.`March 2017`
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Works perfectly. Owe you a beer!!

Comment: @claytont  thanks .. the first time i am in your area .. i would like